# Error while accessing global variable to static function

Tags: java

Hi guys I am new to java I defined a variable as global and tried to access the variable from a static function like the follows:

```
public class PDFEMAIL
{  
    String a = "abc"; 

    public static void main(String args[]) 
    { 
       testme();
    }

    public static void testme()
    {
        System.out.print("Welcome "+a);
    }

}//class end
```

I am getting an error like the follows:

```
error: non-static variable a cannot be referenced from a static context
                                                System.out.println("Welcome"+a);
```

Please help guys. I need out put as "`Welcome abc`"I am new to this!

Comment: So,Make `a` a `static` variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

variable `a` is not static that's why you cannot access it from static method `testMe()`.Change

```
String a = "abc";
```

to

```
static String a = "abc";
```

Answer (score 3):

`a` is not a global variable. Make it `static` if you want it to be global.